# Max length of an input-tag of text type in html?

Tags: html, maxlength

What is the maximum-length (i.e default value) `max-length` of input-value we are able to enter in the html element `<input/>` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input just look for maxlength and read up :)

Comment: Qouted from above comment-link
"If value of the type attribute is text, email, search, password, tel, or url, this attribute specifies maximum number of characters (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter; for other control types, it is ignored. It can exceed the value of the size attribute. If it is not specified, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. Specifying a negative number results in default behavior; that is, the user can enter an unlimited number of characters. The constraint is evaluated only when the value of the attribute has been changed."
Thanks @gillesc

Answer (score 2):

max length is : **524288** ( default )

```
<input type="text" id="myText" maxlength="30000000000">
var x = document.getElementById("myText").maxLength;
document.write( x ) ;
```

show in browser : **524288**

debug : 
Uncaught IndexSizeError: 
Failed to set the 'maxLength' property on 'HTMLInputElement': 
The value provided (-64771072) is negative.

Comment: Verified from chrome's console (**524288**): **document.getElementById('myText').maxLength;**
But please tell me how to do i verify the negative limit. It does not give me any error in the chrome's console. Thanks @ClaudioDaffra

Answer (score 0):

this simple code show you, how verify error ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Username: <input type="text" id="x" maxlength="-1"><br>
<script>
    try
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("x").maxLength=-1;
    }
    catch(err) {
        document.write ( err.message );
    }
    document.write( "<br>" +x ) ;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output :**

Username: 
Failed to set the 'maxLength' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The value provided (-1) is negative.
undefined

Comment: Thanx for the answer, but what is the extreme limit value. @ClaudioDaffra

Comment: But i think the negative value limit is -1.796 e^308 . @ClaudioDaffra